# parsing data from HTML page using VB/C#/ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have saved some HTML pages from the web...now i want to parse some specific data. I mean I want to retrieve some specific part from the HTMl page using VB/C# code. How do I go about it?

Help me with some code examples VB/C#/ASP.NET.

**UPDATE**

I am using this code to read the html file

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
        Dim oRequest As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim oResponse As System.Net.WebResponse
        Dim oReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim sResponse As String
        Try
            oRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(txtURI.Text)
            oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse
            oReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream)
            sResponse = oReader.ReadToEnd
        Catch : sResponse = "Could not load page"
        End Try
        txtHTML.Text = sResponse
    End Sub
```

All i want to do now is to save the specifications to the DATABASE.
1. How do i select the specifications and display them in a ListBox??
2.How do i save it to the DATABASE??

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It's a really nice library for parsing HTML streams and extracting whatever information you might need. Here's an [example](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples).

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's an example of how you could fetch the specifications of the laptop from the following address http://www.sony.co.in/product/vpcea4bgn:

```
Using client = New WebClient()
    client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2"
    Dim doc = New HtmlDocument()
    doc.LoadHtml(client.DownloadString("http://www.sony.co.in/product/vpcea4bgn"))
    Dim specs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='featuresList BodyText']/li/text()")
    For Each spec As HtmlNode In specs
        Dim value = spec.InnerText.Trim()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            ' TODO: Save the specification to your database or something
            Console.WriteLine(value)
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

Notice however that screen scraping is fragile and the day Sony changes their HTML structure your application will fail badly.

Comment: i am a noob in Xpath...so its kinda difficult for me...all i want to do is to read the html and extract a few specs from the html.

Comment: @Sify Juhy, if you are a noob, show the HTML you have and the data you want to extract so that we can help you. At the present state of the question, all we can do is to provide you links to libraries that can help you achieve this task.

Comment: [http://www.sony.co.in/product/vpcea4bgn](http://www.sony.co.in/product/vpcea4bgn) This is the link to the html page..i want to save the html page to my HDD and extract the "Specifications" and save it to my DATABASE.

Comment: @Sify Juhy, I have updated my answer to provide you an example that should get you started with Html Agility Pack.

Comment: i have updated my question...please take a look at it and help me if u can..sorry if am bothering u too much.

Comment: @Sify Juhy, I have already shown you a working version using a WebClient which I consider better. What happened when you tried it? In your example you are using WebRequest/WebResponse/StreamReaders without disposing them properly which possibly could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: do i have to Import the HTML AgilityPack

Comment: @Sify Juhy, once you download and reference the `HtmlAgilityPack.dll` assembly to your project you need to import the `HtmlAgilityPack` namespace in order to bring the `HtmlDocument` classs used in my example into scope.

Comment: @Sify Juhy, I have actually used an online automated C# to VB.NET conversion tool to convert my C# code to VB.NET as I am not a VB.NET expert. I have updated my answer. Try like this `For Each spec As HtmlNode In specs`. Hopefully it will work now.

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: @Sify Juhy, you are behind a proxy. You need to configure it by using the `client.Proxy` property. You really have different questions here. 1. Downloading a remote resource from the internet behind a proxy. 2. Parsing HTML in C#. 3. Querying a SQL database. You should really split your questions into separate if you expect more help as you seem to have troubles with each of those steps (or at least the first 2 as you haven't yet gotten to the third).

Comment: You helped me with the 2 part...please help me with the 1st part as well...i think i will be able to manage with the 3rd part :)

Comment: @Sify Juhy, in order to help you with the first part you will have to provide more details about what proxy server you are using to connect to the internet and what kind of authentication scheme it requires.

Comment: i am in a college ...so my college uses a proxy server..in order to connect to the internet we need to input a user name and password..we have an Ip=172.31.100.29 and Port:3128

Comment: @Sify Juhy, ok for the IP part, but what kind of authentication scheme does this proxy server use? Basic authentication? Integrated Windows Authentication? Something else? Depending on the authentication scheme there might be different ways.

Comment: @Sify Juhy, try setting credentials: `client.Proxy = new WebProxy("172.31.100.29", 3128); client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("some_username", "some_password");`. Also take a look at the following article: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102605-1.aspx

Comment: where does it show me the values??i mean after searching the html file.

Comment: can i use the code with ASP.NET and in VB application(windows desktop application)???

Comment: @Sify Juhy, in my example I am printing the `value` variable to the console. It will contain each `<li>` element value inside the `<ul class='featuresList BodyText">` which currently contains the specifications. And of course that you can use this code in an ASP.NET or Windows Desktop application. You can do whatever you want with the value variable. Html Agility Pack is even available for Silverlight and Windows Phone 7, so you can even write an application parsing HTML on Windows Phone 7 :-)

Comment: Bundled media player "Media Gallery" & creation software "PMB VAIO Edition"  This is the out put i am getting ...i am using a multiline textbox for the output...

Comment: @Sify Juhy, on each iteration of the `For Each` loop you should get a different value of a `<li>` node inside the `value` variable. What happened when you debugged your code?

Comment: i do not get any error...it works fine but does not give the specs...i think thats not the specification part...specification part starts  with<div class="specifications BodyText">

Comment: @Sify Juhy, oh, then adapt the XPath selector to match your requirements. I think I can't help you any more on this. Read the documentation, learn XPath, ...